# How do I alter the submission button class?

Tags: theming

```
 <input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="" name="op" id="edit-submit">
```

I want to alter the class from "form-submit" to "form-submitone".

How can do I do it? Where does the class "form-submit" come from?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If I were you, I would not change the class name but rather add your own class to the form element. You can do this by implementing [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a custom module or (in case of Drupal 7) in your theme. The code would look something like this:

```
<?php
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id = 'my_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-submitone';
  }
}
?>
```

By the way, the submit button element is not necessarily `$form['actions']['submit']`. You will have to figure out which element is the submit button in your specific situation. You can do that by outputting the $form variable; I recommend installing the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and adding `dsm($form);` to the function above.

Comment: how do you know this can give a class to the submit button.$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][]

Comment: It's in the Forms API reference, http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes.

Comment: the api shows as this $form['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('search-form')); why you write as this .$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][]. and have a []? thank you

Comment: If you would do `$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'] = array('form-submitone');`, you would be overriding all classes that are already set. If you would do `$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('form-submitone'));`, you would overwrite not only the  existing classes, but all attributes. (PS See also my addition to the answer above.)

Comment: This works in Drupal 8 too.

Answer (score 0):

this code basically user dor add your custom class on form submit button.

```
function subscriber_form(){
    $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type'  => 'submit',
    '#attributes'=>array('class'=> array('mybtn')),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'subscriber_ajax_callback',
    ),
    '#value' =>'Submit', // @FIXME doesn't render quotes properly
  );

}
```

Comment: this is not correct, the "class" item in the #attributes array needs to be an array: `'class' => array("mybtn-class", "mybtn-class2")`

Comment: Although @devendra answer works, following @DrCord suggestion, it should be `'#attributes' => array('class' => array('mybtn', 'mybtn-2'))`